# why do most finite groups of order 128 resemble (at a distance) the elementary abelian group?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

As a result of [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105282/linearly-arranging-the-group-tables-of-groups-of-order-128), I made the following video:

[Cayley Tables of All Groups of Order 128](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=25Qzu-KuVs4), and what is striking is that most of them, if you squint, kind of resemble the elementary abelian group (gap, SmallGroups(128,2328)):

[image]

- Is there a group-theoretical reason that this might be the case?
- Is there a measure of how far one of these groups is away from being the elementary abelian group?

Comment: You might start by explaining what exactly we are looking at. And then maybe try to give some hint of what you might mean by "resemble".

Comment: We're looking at all the Cayley tables of groups from GAP. I chose the ordering from GAP, so we're looking at SmallGroup(128,n) for n from 1 to 2328. The coloring is linear so element 1 gets mapped to black and element 128 mapped to white.

Comment: It's clear what's being asked.  OP sees a weird pattern in the Cayley table and he wants to know what's up with that.  Perfectly fine question

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, cool movie!

I'm guessing here a bit since I don't know the precise details of how you created the movie and the precise ordering you chose (which might cluster things together in such a way as to 'hide' many cases that look differently). $128$ is very special and allows very little room for variation in the group structure. You will only see interesting subgroups of order $2,4,8, 16, 32, 64$ with the huge majority having subgroups of order $8$, $16$ (I believe). The elementary abelian group is not that far from a group where all elements have order at most, say $8$, so most groups will appear very similar to the elementary abelian group.

Again, this is mostly a guess. You might want to play with sizes that are not a multiple of just a single prime to see if that significantly alters the picture.

Comment: "allows very little room for variation in the group structure" is totally wrong. Among small orders, those that are powers of two allow **vastly** more different group structures than other numbers of about the same size. See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/241369/more-than-99-of-groups-of-order-less-than-2000-are-of-order-1024

Comment: I didn't mean little room for variation in group structure relative to group size, but rather relative to potential  subgroup structures (not subgroup numbers). To clarify, a group of size 128 will (of course) only have subgroups possessing elements of order a power of 2  and every nontrivial subgroup will have an order 2 element. But a group of order 129 will have a subgroup  order 3 or a subgroup of 7. In that respect, even though there are far less non-isomorphic groups of order 129 than there are of order 128, group size 129 allows more variation in subgroup structure than group size 128.